# Next js API undefined parameter

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/success.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";
const Success = () => {
  const {
    query: { id },
  } = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    getId();
  }, [id]);

  const getId = () => {
    axios
      .put("api/getOrder", {
        id,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res.data.session);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.success}>
      <h1>Thank you for your purchase {id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Success;
```

As you may see I am making request to my API once id is loaded

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(`${req.body.id}`)

    res.status(200).send({
        nessage: '200',
        session
    });
    res.status(500).send({
        message: '500'
    });
}
```

This is my BackEnd and I'm passing an id into session variable dynamically. The problem is that it is undefined, but then it completes the request.

This is my console

```
error - StripeInvalidRequestError: No such checkout.session: undefined
    at Function.generate (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:40:16)
    at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeResource.js:238:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'resource_missing',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
    message: 'No such checkout.session: undefined',
    request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_ZrNElSd58VVHSA?t=1666409724',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Sat, 22 Oct 2022 03:35:24 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '311',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'request-id': 'req_ZrNElSd58VVHSA',
      'stripe-version': '2022-08-01',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 404,
    requestId: 'req_ZrNElSd58VVHSA'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'resource_missing',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
  param: undefined,
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Sat, 22 Oct 2022 03:35:24 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '311',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'request-id': 'req_ZrNElSd58VVHSA',
    'stripe-version': '2022-08-01',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_ZrNElSd58VVHSA',
  statusCode: 404,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined,
  page: '/api/getOrder'
}
error - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at Object.sendEtagResponse (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\send-payload\index.js:29:13)
    at sendData (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:172:27)
    at ServerResponse.apiRes.send (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:349:31)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/getOrder.js:12:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:366:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:481:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:735:37) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT',
  page: '/api/getOrder'
}
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at NodeNextResponse.setHeader (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-http\node.js:61:19)
    at DevServer.renderError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1012:17)
    at DevServer.renderError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:843:22)
    at DevServer.run (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:715:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\user\Desktop\zigi\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:285:20) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

This is my console - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqEak.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In absence of `getServerSideProps` and `getInitialProps` functions, next.js applies automatic static optimization on the page. On statically generated pages, the `query` object will always be empty on first render. Check the `router.isReady` flag on the `useEffect` before calling `getId()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js `useRouter()` query parameter will be empty during prerender if you don't use SSR.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).